# Android Progress dialog don't show until the end of onClick method

Tags: android, onclick, dialog, progressdialog, progress

I'm trying to display a progress dialog when sign in button is clicked. But the progress dialog is displayed only when i reach the end of my method onClick. And not a the start. 
In the signIn method, i do a asynctask to reach the server. 
So all the time take by the asynctask, there is no progress dialog displayed. only when the end of the onClick method is reach, the progress dialog is displayed....
Some one know what am i doing wrong?

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Sign in in progress");
            progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

            progressDialog.show();

            repSignIn = signIn(SignIn.this, etEmail.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString());


            if(!repSignIn.hasError())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign In successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onBackPressed();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), repSignIn.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //progressDialog.cancel();
        }
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Nadine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change my code

```
 String result = new sendDataToServer().execute(url, "PUT", jsonData.toString()).get();
```

By doing this:

https://gist.github.com/cesarferreira/ef70baa8d64f9753b4da

And now it's work very well.

Thanks for your help. =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `progressDialog` in onClick you need to put it in `onPreExecute` of your `AsyncTask` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute`.

The reason is `AsyncTask` uses a worker thread that will be asynchronous and that is the reason why `progressDialog` finishes before expected.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // do your stuff
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: But the asynctask is inside a librairie (that i develop). So i don't want to put the progress dialog in the onProExecute... i want to display before launch the asynctask...

Comment: is there any callback from library, does the asyncTask return anything?

Comment: In the method in librairy, i call the asynctask ans i wait on it result.  String result = new sendDataToServer().execute(url, "PUT", jsonData.toString()).get(); It's the problem?

Comment: You will never get the response correct as get is synchronous method and asyncTask runs asynchronously, rather override the asyncTask, hook your code and then execute that object

Answer (score 0):

In Async task override onPreExecute() method and there you have to display the progress bar..

```
private void signIn(your parameters here) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                 progressDialog.setMessage("Sign in in progress");
                 progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
                 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                 progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                 progressDialog.show();
            }

             @Override
            protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                 //your logic here
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
                 super.onPostExecute(response);
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
          }.execute();
     }
```

HOpe this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use your progress dailog in Asyntask. Initialise and start your dialog in onPreExecute and dismiss dialog in onPostExecute. 
working for me,

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progress = new ProgressDialog(UpdateActivity.this);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.setMessage("Please wait data is Processing");
    progress.show();
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progress.dismiss();

}
```